# SQLite returned error code 1 = no column

Tags: android

I was trying to insert new data int my database called KEY_DAY but when it displays an err

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the column in your create table statement :

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_DAY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
```

Comment: its still showing me an error "Database(506): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table peopleTable has no column named persons_day"

Comment: It shows u because the database is still exist try uninstalling or increment the value of DATABASE_VERSION (if u change value of DATABASE_VERSION then onUpgrade will be called for recreation of database)